# Initialization of reference member requires a temporary variable

Tags: c++, reference, struct

```
struct Div
{
   int i;
   int j;
};   

class A
{
public:
    A();
    Div& divs;
};
```

In my constructor definition, I have the following implementation

```
A::A(): divs(NULL)
{}
```

I get the following error:

> Error72 error C2354:  'A::divs' : initialization of reference member
> requires a temporary variable

Answer (score 39, accepted):

A reference must be initialised to refer to something; it can't refer to nothing, so you can't default-construct a class that contains one (unless, as others suggest, you define a global "null" value). You will need a constructor that is given the `Div` to refer to:

```
explicit A(Div &d) : divs(d) {}
```

If you want it to be able to be "null", then you need a pointer, not a reference.

Comment: It is generally not true that you can't default-construct a class with a reference member. For example, the reference can be bound to an object declared at namespace scope ("global" object, in simpler words).

Comment: As noted, you can do a default constructor if you use a predefined variable (as in my example below).

Comment: You're both correct. However, I would advise against using a global "null" value - it can't be const, so the default behaviour would be to use a global object that any other instance of the class can change without notice.

Answer (score 13):

divs is a reference, not a pointer. You can't set it to NULL, it has to point to an actual object of some kind. The best thing to do here is probably to define a static/global instance of Div that you arbitrarily define to be the "Null Div" (set its value to something you're unlikely ever to use) and initialize div to that. Something like this:

```
struct Div
{
   int i;
   int j;
};   

Div NULL_DIV = { INT_MAX, INT_MAX };

class A
{
    public:
             A();
             Div& divs;
};


A::A() : divs(NULL_DIVS)
{
}
```

Or, alternatively, just make divs a pointer instead of a reference.

*Note that you can't use a const reference unless you cast away the constness because by default the compiler won't allow you to assign a cosnt ref to a non-const ref.

Comment: you're initializing non-const ref with const object. Does it compile?

Answer (score 8):

For one, you can't have a NULL reference.  As second, all variable references in a class must be initialized at construction time.

Comment: @varun: you need to initialize your reference to a valid object instance at time of construction (i.e. in your constructor).

Comment: @varun: note that you can go for a pointer if that makes your life easier... or refactor.

Comment: thanks guys for the response! i decided to go with pointer .. made my life much easier!

Answer (score 6):

In "English": a reference refers to *something*. It cannot refer to *nothing* (null). That's why references are safer to use then pointers.

Comment: Not just in english. The exact same is true in C++.

Answer (score 3):

References have to reference something. There is no such thing as a null reference in the C++ language. If the member may not have a value, then it should be a pointer, or a `boost::optional` or some type like that.

A reference must be initialized to reference a valid object.

Answer (score 3):

Keep in mind that once a reference is initialized to point to something, you cannot alter it to point to something else.  If this is not the desired behavior, then you should use a pointer or a copy of the object instead.

Answer (score 3):

The compiler message is one of those messages that don't make sense from the language point of view, but reveal the inner workings of the compiler, the sequence in which its inner logic works.

In your case you are using an rvalue (`NULL`) to initialize a reference. When such initialization is allowed, the rvalue is converted to a temporary object, to which the reference will be bound. So, the compiler has realized it right away and informed you about the fact with a diagnostic message.

In reality though, the trick like that is only allowed for `const` references, so your code is broken, since the reference is not `const` in our case. Also, a `struct` reference, as the one in your code, cannot be initialized with `NULL` rvalue (which has integral type), so it is broken for that reason as well.

The compiler's message is rather misleading though. The text of the message seems to imply that it is illegal to initialize member references with temporary objects. In fact, this is legal in C++ (once the above problems are fixed), although it makes no sense. But, I guess, once ill-formed code is accompanied by at least some error message, it should be OK for everyone...

Answer (score 2):

Plain and simple:

A reference can never be NULL.

Answer (score 1):

You should try and initialise your "divs" variable. You cannot have a reference refering to "nothing"...

Have a look here :

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bbt3ewya%28VS.80%29.aspx

Hope this help a bit!

Answer (score 1):

As noted in other posts, references (Div&) cannot be null. So the most straightforward change you can make is to provide a reference in the constructor and initialize your reference member. Like this,

```
class A
{
    public:
             A(Div& inDivs);
             Div& divs;

};

public A::A( Div& inDivs )
: divs( inDivs )
{}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
class A
{
    Div & ref(Div div) { return div; }
    public:
       A() : divs(ref(Div())) {};
       Div& divs;
};
```

Comment: Although this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding why and/or how it answers the question would significantly improve its long-term value. 
Please edit your answer to add some explanation.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest:

```
class A{
    std::deque<object*>& que = *(std::deque<object*> *)0;
    // ...
    // Of course `que` is to  be assigned valid deque before using it - just like pointers...
};
```

Comment: Please add some text with your code describing why you would suggest it. The question already has an accepted answer, so an explanation why your answer is valid too/better, would help a lot.

Comment: I'm sorry I did not understand why I have to explain the reason for using this solution - except that it shows that it works.

Comment: It might work in some implementations, but it's not conforming. If you want a pointer, just use a pointer, instead of such shenanigans that completely violate the intent of references.

Comment: You refer to "violation of intents" ? 

Then my answer is "C++ itself is a violation of all operating systems". In C++, you have to hack all the way downto system/kernel calls. Not talking about total linking  incompatilbilities using DLL's/*.so without  C-interface hacks-cure. So don't make me laugh out loud, please...