# Initialising reference in constructor C++

Tags: c++, constructor

I don't think is a duplicate question.  There are similar ones but they're not helping me solve my problem.

According to [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/szywdw8k.aspx), the following is valid in C++:

```
class c {
public:
   int& i;
};
```

However, when I do this, I get the following error:

```
error: uninitialized reference member 'c::i'
```

How can I initialise successfully do `i=0`on construction?

Many thanks.

Comment: Could you tell us more about you're real problem please?

Comment: Sounds like you want a pointer.

Comment: @Mikhail, [Bjarne Stroustrup](http://www.stroustrup.com) does not like pointers. I wonder what he would do, I assume not use pointers.

Comment: @user34660 Many C++ libraries use pointers, for example Qt has objects whose lifetimes are managed by their parent. The object is used with a pointer (just don't call delete on it!)

Comment: @user34660 Got a specific link to that? Couldn't find him saying that.

Comment: @SimonC yes that is likely now missing in his website. I assume it has been moved to one of his books. So all I can say is that he has stated he invented references because he does not like pointers. If the only reason to use pointers is because you don't know how to do something using references then it is better to ask how to use references, as in this question.

Answer (score 47, accepted):

There is no such thing as an "empty reference". You **have** to provide a reference at object initialization. Put it in the constructor's base initializer list:

```
class c
{
public:
  c(int & a) : i(a) { }
  int & i;
};
```

An alternative would be `i(*new int)`, but that'd be terrible.

**Edit:** To maybe answer your question, you probably just want `i` to be a member object, not a reference, so just say `int i;`, and write the constructor either as `c() : i(0) {}` or as `c(int a = 0) : i(a) { }`.

Comment: "An alternative would be i(*new int), but that'd be terrible." It wouldn't if the DTOR calls `delete` on that pointer.

Comment: @Constantinius: It'd still be fairly horrible even if you remembered to clean up... just think about assignments, copies, exception safety, etc...

Comment: For example: if your class has another data member that's initialized after `i`, or if it has code in the body of the constructor, and that code throws an exception, then the destructor isn't called and the resource is leaked. If a class holds a resource, that really should be the *only* thing it does. But of course if you were designing a class to hold an `int` that was solely owned by that object then you wouldn't use a reference member, you'd use an `int` member, so this "problem" doesn't arise in practice.

Comment: Of course not, but I assumed the `int&` and `int*` are just placeholders for more interesting entities. @Kerrek: Sure, there are many things to be thought of. But ideas like the pImpl idiom sure point out that this strategy is legitimate. Also no one would blame you for using smart pointers that are useful for exactly what you are pointing out.

Answer (score 5):

Apart from the sweet syntax, a key feature of references is that you are pretty sure that it always point to a value (No NULL value).

When designing an API, it forces user to not send you NULL.
When consuming an API, you know without reading the doc that NULL is not an option here.

Comment: >"you are pretty sure that it always point to a value" Wrong. u can have dangeling references

Answer (score 5):

> [A reference must be initialised to
>   refer to something](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1701416/initialization-of-reference-member-requires-a-temporary-variable-c).

```
int a;
class c {
public:
   int& i;
   c() : i (a) {};
};
```

Answer (score 0):

References have to be initialized upon creation. Thus you have to initialize it when the class is created. Also you have to provide some legal object to reference.

You have to use the initializer in your constructor:

```
class c {
public:
   c(const int& other) : i(other) {}
   int& i;
};
```

Comment: That's a terrible terrible thing to do.

Comment: Dangling reference to temporary?

Comment: you should add another const then.

Comment: @poulejapon: It would not prevent dangling reference to temporary.

Comment: I know you edited, but the problem remains that your class allows someone to write `c myc(0)` or `c myc(1+1)`, and the resulting object `myc` has a dangling reference to a temporary that was destroyed at the end of construction. It's generally safer to take a pointer or non-const reference in functions that are going to keep a pointer/reference to an object, since it gives the user a better chance of noticing that they're responsible for ensuring that referand has a suitable lifetime. OK, people should RTFM, but nothing reminds them to do that like a compiler error.

Comment: @DeadMG, I know, I already pointed out the mistake on the first version. For the second version, I actually saw a few cases for which it made sense to have a const reference member.

Comment: If was to use such a thing I would put have the copy constructor private, and possibly prevent allocation on the heap as much as possible.

Answer (score -2):

Reference should be initialised either by passing data to constructor or allocate memory from heap if you want to initialize in default constructor.

```
class Test  
{  
    private:
        int& val;  
        std::set<int>& _set;  
    public:  
        Test() : val (*(new int())),  
                _set(*(new std::set<int>())) {  }  

        Test(int &a, std::set<int>& sett) :  val(a), _set(sett) {  }  
};  

int main()  
{  
    cout << "Hello World!" << endl;  
    Test obj;  
    int a; std::set<int> sett;  
    Test obj1(a, sett);  
    return 0;  
}
```

---

Thanks