# Uninitialized reference member

Tags: c++

Basically what I want to do is store the reference to the active animation of a sprite as a private member in the Actor class. I want to use a reference so I don't have to actually create the animation multiple times but I keep getting an error.

Actor class declaration:

```
class Actor
{
public:
        Actor();
        ~Actor();
        void setActiveAnimation(Animation anim);
        void draw(sf::RenderWindow& win);

private:
        sf::Sprite sprite;
        MaJR::Animation& activeAnimation;
};
```

Actor class implementation:

```
Actor::Actor()
{
    // constructor
}

Actor::~Actor()
{
    // destructor
}

void Actor::setActiveAnimation(Animation anim)
{
    activeAnimation = anim;
    activeAnimation.gotoStart();
}

void Actor::draw(sf::RenderWindow& win)
{
    sprite.setTexture(activeAnimation.getActiveFrame());
    win.draw(sprite);
    activeAnimation.nextFrame();
}
```

Build output:

```
/home/mike/MaJR Game Engine/src/Actor.cpp||In constructor 'MaJR::Actor::Actor()':|
/home/mike/MaJR Game Engine/src/Actor.cpp|8|error: uninitialized reference member 'MaJR::Actor::activeAnimation' [-fpermissive]|
||=== Build finished: 1 errors, 0 warnings ===|
```

Comment: it seems ["Initialising reference in constructor C++"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6576109/initialising-reference-in-constructor-c) first answer, is the answer you were looking for

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Initialising reference in constructor C++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6576109/initialising-reference-in-constructor-c)

Answer (score 34, accepted):

A reference cannot be *reassigned*, so it must be initialized at the *member-initialization-list*. However, you intend to reassign it so what you want is not a reference. What's more, in your `setActiveAnimation` function you are setting such reference to a copy of the value passed as an argument, which leaves you with an invalid reference when the code exits the function. Perhaps a pointer would suit you?

In the class body:

```
MaJR::Animation* activeAnimation;
```

And the `setActiveAnimation` function:

```
void Actor::setActiveAnimation(Animation* anim)
{
    activeAnimation = anim;
    activeAnimation->gotoStart();
}
```

Comment: Your analysis is good, but I can't upvote an answer with code that stores the address of a parameter passed by reference.  If you're storing a pointer for later use, accept a pointer parameter, to make the caller more aware of the lifetime considerations.

Comment: @Ben Voigt: I wouldn't know, I don't use _raw pointers_ in my code at all.

Comment: I agree that a raw pointer isn't as good as a smart pointer.  But a reference is much much worse.  +1 for the fix.

Comment: So what's going on is Actor::activeAnimation is a pointer to the anim which is a pointer to the original Animation correct? What's a smart pointer and how do they differ from a raw pointer?

Comment: @Mike: They differ in that they are _smart_. For instance, a `shared_ptr` looks and feels just like a pointer, but the ownership is shared (it implements reference counting and automatically deletes the resource when the last reference dies). A `unique_ptr` is a pointer that can be moved around but cannot be copied, to guarantee a _unique_ owner of the pointer.

Comment: A shared_ptr sounds like it would be the best way to go for this then. From what I just read it should be declared `std::shared_ptr<MaJR::Animation>` but then I can't call functions from the Animation class. Pointers are confusing >.<

Comment: @Mike: You use it just like any other pointer, i.e. `activeAnimation->someFunction();`

Comment: I mean in the pointers declaration. Instead of `MaJR::Animation* activeAnimation` it looks like I should declare it `std::shared_ptr<MaJR::Animation> activeAnimation(new MaJR::Animation());` but that just brings up a ton of more errors. Everywhere I see about shared_ptr that's how it's declared so I'm not sure what's going wrong.

Comment: Anyways thanks for the help, I'll read up more on smart pointers and see if I can get this working.

Comment: @Mike: That's because they are declared and initialized at the same time. You don't need to initialize, it will be null.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/12322/discussion-between-mike-and-k-ballo)

Answer (score 8):

When you have a member in your class that is a reference, you MUST initialize it in the constructor.  Once it's initialized, you can't change it anymore (well you can change the value but not where it refers to).

Make activeAnimation a pointer instead.

Answer (score 3):

You cannot declare an uninitialized reference. That means you need to either initialized the reference when you create an object from class `Actor` or you cannot use a reference. If you need to dynamically change it, then you could use a pointer or, probably better, a *smart pointer* (e.g., [std::unique_ptr](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/unique_ptr), [shared_ptr](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/shared_ptr)). If you cannot use C++11, then have a look at [smart pointers](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_49_0/libs/smart_ptr/smart_ptr.htm) from Boost.

Answer (score 2):

You need to bind a reference at definition time.  For member references this means in the initializer list of the constructor.  Moreover the binding cannot be re-assigned after declaration.

If you don't have the object (to get the reference to) at instatiation time of `Actor` objects, your next best bet is to use pointers which can be reassigned later on as needed.