# C++ Initialization list for reference variables

Tags: c++, reference

I am trying to initialize a reference object through the initialization list in the class constructor and I would need your inputs on why I am not able to initialize it in the following way. Am I not allowed to initialize a reference in the following way?

```
class ObjectA
{

private:
    char* _nameA; 
    int _velocityA;

public:
        ObjectA(char* name, int velocity)
        {
            name = name;
            _velocityA = velocity;
        }
};
```

I get an error in the following initialization list which says **a reference of type "ObjectA &" (not const-qualified) cannot be initialized with a value of type "char *"** Why exactly am I getting this error? and what am I doing wrong?

```
class ObjectB
{

private:
    ObjectA& objA;

public:
        ObjectB(char* engName, int _velocityA):objA(engName, _velocityA)
        {
        }
};
```

Comment: well if it would be `ObjectA` and not `ObjectA&` I'd say that you should use `:objA(ObjectA(engName,_velocityA))` but `objA` is a reference and you shouldn't take the reference to an RValue.

Comment: already the fact that ObjectA has a member char* which points to some object outside of the class may later cause you trouble since it makes ObjectA instances not self-contained.

Comment: Yeah you should use a `std::string` if you want to store a sequence of caracter representing a name.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is you tried to initialize the reference `objA` in the same way you create an object.

```
ObjectB(char* engName, int _velocityA):objA(engName, _velocityA)
    {
    }
```

Remember `objA` is a reference, not a pointer or a variable so that `objA(engName, _velocityA)` would call the constructor of `ObjectA`.

The constructor of `ObjectB` should take an `ObjectA` object as parameter, so that the reference `objA` can refer.

```
class ObjectB
{

private:
ObjectA& objA;

public:
    ObjectB(ObjectA & a):objA(a)
    {
    }
};

int main()
{
    ObjectA a("hello", 10);
    ObjectB *b = new ObjectB(a) ;

}
```

Answer (score 3):

What you are trying to do here doesn't make any sense. You are trying to initialize a **reference** with a newly created object. A reference needs to point to an **existing** object. If you can't have one, then a reference might not be what you want.

See this question for more informations : [Initialization of reference member requires a temporary variable C++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1701416/initialization-of-reference-member-requires-a-temporary-variable-c)