# Reference members and uninitialized objects (design related)

Tags: c++, interface, reference

I have a `Playable` class which is inherited by two different classes: `Note` and `Track.`
The `Track` class has a member of the type `Generator` which is used very often and is quite large. Track also has a multimap of Note-objects. Every note that is created is always added to the right Track.

My problem is that there's a few occasions where the Note class also needs access to `Tracks` `Generator-member.`

I wanted to accomplish this by giving Note a `Track &trackReference` member so that I could find the right `Generator` through `trackReference` but the problem with this is that I can't use a default constructor because the reference can't be empty. And there are times when my Note objects are just empty so I really need a default constructor for Note.

So how do I implement this so that I can acces the Generator object from every Note?

Comment: Make it a pointer (`Track*`)? Or `boost::optional<Track&>`? Btw, why do you need a reference to the track, not the `Generator`?

Comment: Does it make sense to have a singleton "null" implementation of Track that can be used as a placeholder?

Comment: Singleton doesn't really make sense in this case.

Comment: See my answer for a little more description about my suggestion.  A singleton doesn't make sense generally, but a single "empty" object may make sense for you.

Answer (score 1):

If your design allows for a null implementation, that is a possible route.  Here's an example:

```
class foo
{
public:
   virtual void bar() = 0;
};

class null_foo
   : public foo
{
   virtual void bar() {}
};

class C
{
public:
   C(foo& f) : ref(f)  {}
   C() : ref(null_foo) {};

private:
   foo& ref;
};
```

Here's a [related question.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1701416/initialization-of-reference-member-requires-a-temporary-variable-c)

Comment: This really doesn't make any sense. A "null implementation" only makes sense with an interface, otherwise it's not really "null" / "empty" and may provide *nasty* wrong behaviour.

Answer (score 0):

You can simply use `Track*` in place of `Track&` and it also have many advantage for implementing functions that you can't have with references. For example:

```
bool HasParent() {return trackReference != NULL;}
Track& track() {return *trackReference;}
```

Comment: What if I call `track()` even if `HasParent()` is false?  There is no way to prevent that at compile time.

Comment: You can throw an exception for this( this is at runtime I know that! ) but with other ways of doing that (reference is not possible with C++, `boost::optional` and ...) can you detect it at compile time?? your problem is dynamic at nature (calling an object in an invalid state) so how you want to solve it at compile time??

Comment: I'm just asking what is the benefit of using a reference if you're already storing it as a pointer?  Better to just let the pointer be used, where a `NULL` dereference is at least expected behavior in the worst case.

Comment: OK! But references can only used where you can initialize object in construction time (since their value can't changed) that you can't do it here and as you already know they are actively pointers (with some kind of support in the language) so every time that you want to reinitialize a reference the most obvious choice is pointer!!

Comment: I'm not disagreeing, I just think if you're already storing a pointer, _especially for the case of an optional value_, that there is very little to gain by passing that around by reference.