# Create a static class variable inside another class, use of deleted function = error

Tags: c++, oop

I have a class Dog and a class Owner. In class Dog there is a member which is a reference to a specimen of class Owner (breeder). So i need this specimen to be created when i have at least 1 Dog specimen and to be shared and used in their constructors by other Dog examplars.

```
class Dog 
    {
       private:
         Owner & m_owner;
         ...
       public:
           static Owner & m_breeder;
         ...
    }

class Owner
    {private:
         ...
     public:
         ...
      }
```

dog.cpp

```
  {
    #include "dog_class.h"
    #include <iostream>
    #include <cstdlib>
    #include <string>
    #include <ctime>

    Owner breeder("breeder");
    Owner & Dog::m_breeder=breeder;
    //methods here
    Dog () : m_owner(m_breeder) {}

    ...
  }
```

This doesn't work (error:use of deleted function 'Dog & Dog::operator=(const Dog&);
I tried to include Owner as "static Owner breeder;" in public section of class Dog and later initialize it inside dog.cpp but it doesn't work either.
What's wrong and how my goal can be obtained?

---

Here some more code, basically, constructors of class Dog and Owner:

dog_class_methods.cpp

```
Dog::Dog(std::string name, int size, int status, int loyalty, int sex, int price, std::vector<Dog> * market, Owner & owner) : m_owner(owner)
{
m_name=name;
m_size=size;
m_status=status;
m_loyalty=loyalty;

m_sex=sex;
m_price=price;
m_market=market; //pointer to the market
m_market->push_back(*this);
//break_out();
 }



  Dog::Dog() : m_owner(m_breeder)
{
m_name="Fang";
srand(time(NULL));
m_size=(rand()%10)+1; //small: random number from 1 to 10;
m_status=0; //not owned
m_loyalty=(rand()%10)+1; //from 1 to 10
Owner no_one("no_one");
//m_owner=no_one;
m_sex=rand()%2; //rand 0 or 1;
m_price=rand()%1001; //0 - 1000;
//show_data();
//break_out();
 }
```

owner_class_methods.cpp

```
Owner::Owner()
{

m_name="random";
m_goodness=(rand()%10+1);
m_size=(rand()%10+1);
m_money=rand()%1001;
m_agility=(rand()%10+1);
m_int=(rand()%10+1);
//std::cout<<"Hi! I am the "<<m_name<<std::endl;
 }
  Owner::Owner(std::string name)
 {
 if (name=="no one")
 {
m_name="no one";
m_goodness=0;
m_size=0;
m_money=0;
m_agility=0;
m_int=0;
std::cout<<"Hi! I am the "<<m_name<<std::endl;
   }
   else
  {
m_name=name;
m_goodness=(rand()%10+1);
m_size=(rand()%10+1);
m_money=rand()%1001;
m_agility=(rand()%10+1);
m_int=(rand()%10+1);
std::cout<<"The '"<<m_name<<"' owner made"<<std::endl;
    }
  }


 Owner::Owner(std::string name, int goodness, int size, int money, int    agility, std::vector<Dog> doglist)
  {
m_name=name;
m_size=size;
m_money=money;
m_agility=agility;
for (int i=0;  i<doglist.size();i++)
    m_doglist.push_back(doglist[i]);
  }
```

"use of deleted function 'Dog& Dog::operator=(const Dog&)" keeps arising!! Please, help!

Comment: You might want to post some more code...

Comment: References cannot be initialized like that see: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1701416/initialization-of-reference-member-requires-a-temporary-variable-c , and I believe you are missing a lot of code and the exact error messages for us to figure out what's wrong.

Comment: `Dog () : m_owner(breeder) {}` is correct, the error message must be coming from some other line.

Comment: The second code sample should not have the outer `{ }`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
class Dog {
    Dog(Owner& owner)
    : m_owner(owner)
    {}
    Owner& m_owner;
};

Owner breeder("breeder");
Dog the_dog(breeder);
```

Answer (score 0):

The error appeared because there was a use of vector which required for Dog objects to be copyable, but there was a reference member in class and operator= needed to be written:

```
  Dog Dog::operator=(const Dog & a)
 {    m_owner=a.m_owner;
      m_loyalty=a.m_loyalty;
      m_size=a.m_size;
      m_status=a.m_status;
      m_sex=a.m_sex;
      m_price=a.m_price;
      m_market=a.m_market; //market один для всех собак;
      m_name=a.m_name;
      return *this;
 }
```

This solved the whole thing.

```
package services;

import java.util.Scanner;

/**
 * This class contain the main method for testing
 * the Service class and the methods for getting user input.
 */
public class Pr6 {
    /**
     * A Scanner is used to get user input.
     */
    private static Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);

    /**
     * This method runs the program.
     * @param args none expected.
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        boolean quit = false;
        do  {
            int choice = getUserChoiceFunction();

            switch (choice)  {
                case 1:
                    System.out.println("\n==== Testing countVowels ====");

                    String s = getVowelsString();
                    int count = Services.countVowels(s);
                    System.out.println("\nThere are " + count + " vowels in this string!");

                    break;
                case 2:
                    System.out.println("\n==== Testing fill ====");

                    int n = getArraySize();
                    int a = getA();
                    int b = getB(a);

                    int[] array = Services.fill(n, a, b);
                    System.out.print("\nResult array: ");
                    print(array);

                    break;
                case 3:
                    quit = true;
                    break;
            }
        } while (!quit);
    }

    /**
     * This method prints a given array.
     * @param array the array to print.
     */
    private static void print(int[] array)  {
        System.out.print("[");

        for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
            System.out.print(array[i]);

            if (i < array.length - 1)  {
                System.out.print(", ");
            }
        }

        System.out.println("]");
    }

    /**
     * This method gets the upper bound b.
     *
     * It must be greater than lower bound a.
     *
     * @param a lower bound.
     * @return upper bound.
     */
    private static int getB(int a)  {
        do  {
            System.out.print("\nEnter b: ");

            int b = scanner.nextInt();
            scanner.nextLine();

            if (a < b)  {
                return b;
            }

            System.out.println("Error! a should be less than b!");
        } while (true);
    }

    /**
     * This method gets the lower bound a.
     * @return the lower bound.
     */
    private static int getA()  {
        System.out.print("\nEnter a: ");

        int a = scanner.nextInt();
        scanner.nextLine();

        return a;
    }

    /**
     * This method gets the size of the array.
     *
     * It should be greater than zero.
     *
     * @return the size of the array.
     */
    private static int getArraySize()  {
        do  {
            System.out.print("\nEnter n: ");

            int n = scanner.nextInt();
            scanner.nextLine();

            if (n <= 0)  {
                System.out.println("Error! n must be greater than 0!");
            }
            else  {
                return n;
            }
        } while (true);
    }

    /**
     * This method gets the string to count vowels in.
     * @return the string provided by the user.
     */
    private static String getVowelsString()  {
        System.out.print("\nEnter string: ");
        String input = scanner.nextLine();
        return input;
    }

    /**
     * This method allows a user to pick a choice
     * from a given menu.
     * @return the user choice.
     */
    public static int getUserChoiceFunction()  {
        do  {
            System.out.println("\n1. countVowels" +
                    "\n2. fill" +
                    "\n3. Quit");
            System.out.print("\nYour choice: ");

            int choice = scanner.nextInt();
            scanner.nextLine();

            if (choice >= 1 && choice <= 3)  {
                return choice;
            }

            System.out.println("\nError! Wrong choice!");
        } while (true);
    }
}
```

```
package services;

import java.util.Random;

/**
 * This class contains countVowels and fill methods.
 */
public class Services {
    /**
     * This method counts and returns the number of vowels
     * in a given string.
     *
     * Vowels are letters: A, E, I, O, U.
     *
     * The count is case-insensitive.
     *
     * @param s the string.
     * @return the number of vowels in the string.
     */
    public static int countVowels(String s)  {
        char[] vowels = {'a', 'e', 'i', 'o', 'u'};
        int count = 0;

        for (char letter: s.toCharArray())  {
            for (char vowel: vowels)  {
                if (Character.toLowerCase(letter) == vowel)  {
                    count++;
                }
            }
        }

        return count;
    }

    /**
     * This method creates and fills an array of size n
     * with random number in the range [a; b].
     *
     * @param n the size of the array.
     * @param a the lower bound of the random numbers.
     * @param b the upper bound of the random numbers.
     * @return the array of size n filled with random
     * numbers in range [a; b].
     */
    public static int[] fill(int n, int a, int b)  {
        int[] array = new int[n];

        for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
            array[i] = generateRandomNumber(a, b + 1);
        }

        return array;
    }

    /**
     * Generates a random number in a given range.
     *
     * @param min inclusive lower bound.
     * @param max exclusive upper bound.
     * @return the random number in range [min; max).
     */
    private static int generateRandomNumber(int min, int max) {
        Random random = new Random();
        return random.nextInt(max - min) + min;
    }
}
```